# How to use getUrl() in Chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

im using chrome custom tabs (webview) but doesn't work getUrl() and getTitle() function. how to make this?

```
 final CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
                intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimary));
                intentBuilder.setShowTitle(false);
                //intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(urll));
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be like this "https://www.google.co/" added https before url

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: could you please check the URL you passing